# Is convex set interval or ray?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

> Given an ordered set $X$, say a subset $Y$ of $X$ is **convex** in $X$ if for each pair of points $a<b$ of $Y$, the entire interval $(a,b)$ of points of $X$ lies in $Y$. An **interval** is of the form $(a,b),(a,b],[a,b),[a,b]$, and a **ray** is of the form $(a,+\infty),(-\infty,a),[a,+\infty),(-\infty,a]$.
>
> Let $X$ be an ordered set. If $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$, does it follow that $Y$ is an interval or a ray in $X$?

Well, suppose $Y$ has a smallest element $a$ and a largest element $b$. Then $[a,b]\in Y$, and so $Y=[a,b]$ and $Y$ is an interval.

What if $Y$ has no smallest element? So for each element $a\in Y$, there exists an element $b\in Y$ such that $b<a$. What then?

Comment: Is it a partial order or a total order?

Comment: @StefanH. It is total.

Comment: Always good for counterexamples is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is this homework? It's straight out of Munkres.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip It is indeed straight out of Munkres, but I'm doing it for self-study :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Let $X$ be the set of non-zero real numbers with the usual order, and let $Y$ be the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: I realize that (0,infinity) is not a ray as Munkres defines it since 0 is not an element of X, however, why does he define it that way? It seems like we should be free to use elements outside the set to help us simply describe a set we want to talk about.

Comment: @H_1317 Same reason end points of open intervals in X are elements of X, I think. Or do you ask about open intervals too? Btw, what then of closed rays, closed intervals or half-open intervals?

Comment: @H_1317: (I apparently missed your question back in 2018; an answer may still be useful to some reader.) Let $$X_1=\big(\{0\}\times Y\big)\cup\big(\Bbb R\times\{0\}\big)\,,$$ and define a linear order $\preceq$ on $X_1$ by letting $\langle x,0\rangle\preceq\langle y,0\rangle$ iff $x\le y$, $\langle 0,x\rangle\preceq\langle 0,y\rangle$ iff $x\le y$, and $\langle 0,x\rangle\preceq\langle y,0\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. ...

Comment: ... Let $Y_1=\Bbb R\times\{0\}$, and let $h:X_1\to X$ be defined as follows: $h(\langle 0,x\rangle)=-\frac1x$, and $h(\langle x,0\rangle=e^x$. Then $h$ is an order-isomorphism between $\langle X_1,\preceq\rangle$ and $\langle X,\le\rangle$ that sends $Y_1$ to $Y$, so from an order-theoretic point of view the structure $\langle X_1,Y_1,\preceq\rangle$ is indistinguishable from the structure $\langle X,Y,\le\rangle$. In particular, $Y_1$ is a convex subset of $X_1$. And when I present the example this way, there is no handy point that you could use to make $Y_1$ a ray. The point $0$ works ...

Comment: ... in the original presentation **only** because I embedded the order in $\Bbb R$ in a very nice way. When I embed it in $\Bbb R^2$ as I did above, there is no such point, yet it is for all practical purposes the same linear order with the same convex subset. In short, when answering the question of whether $Y$ is a ray in $X$, you are working strictly in $X$ and have no access to anything outside of $X$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What about $X = \mathbb{Q}$ with usual order inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, and $Y = (0, \pi) \cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Sushant: Very good example: in that case $Y$ is convex but is neither an interval nor a ray in $X$.